# Can't get Discord.Py bot to play more then one song

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I get my bot to play a single song so far but only when it connects to the voice channel for the first time. When I try to put another song in after doing a stop command I get this

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.

I mean yes I know its in a voice channel but why won't it play more then one song?

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="^")
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return

    voiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))

    while voice.is_playing():  # Makes other commands no longer work
        print("playing...")
        time.sleep(5)

    else:
        song_queue.remove(song)
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")



@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()





client.run('')
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the voice client, check if its connected.

```py
voiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
# If bot is currently connected to voice channel
if voice is not None:
    # If bot is connected to different voice channel than author
    if voice.channel != voiceChannel:
        await voice.move_to(voiceChannel)
     # If move_to doesn't work try below:
        #await voice.disconnect()
        #await voiceChannel.connect()
else:
    await voiceChannel.connect()
```

You might want to check ctx.author.voice is not None. Current code gives an exception when author is not connected to any voice channel.